# Running a MR Job on a portion of the HDFS file

Tags: hadoop

Imagine you have a big file stored in hdtf which contains structured data. Now the goal is to process only a portion of data in the file like all the lines in the file where second column value is between so and so. Is it possible to launch the MR job such that hdfs only stream the relevant portion of the file versus streaming everything to the mappers.

The reason is that I want to expedite the job speed by only working on the portion that I need. Probably one approach is to run a MR job to get create a new file but I am wondering if one can avoid that?

Please note that the goal is to keep the data in HDFS and I do not want to read and write from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HDFS stores files as a bunch of bytes in blocks, and there is no indexing, and therefore no way to only read in a portion of your file (at least at the time of this writing).  Furthermore, any given mapper may get the first block of the file or the 400th, and you don't get control over that.

That said, the whole point of MapReduce is to distribute the load over many machines.  In our cluster, we run up to 28 mappers at a time (7 per node on 4 nodes), so if my input file is 1TB, each map slot may only end up reading 3% of the total file, or about 30GB.  You just perform the filter that you want in the mapper, and only process the rows you are interested in.

If you really need filtered access, you might want to look at storing your data in HBase.  It can act as a native source for MapReduce jobs, provides filtered reads, and stores its data on HDFS, so you are still in the distributed world.

Comment: Coprocessors introduced in 0.92 can also be used to filter out the data similar to the filters. Not exactly sure what's the difference between coprocessors and filters is. One thing I can think is, filters are defined at the client, while the coprocessors are defined on the server. So, coprocessors are reusable across clients. One thing to note is that both filters and coprocessors execute on the server and cut down the data sent to the client.

Comment: Good point Praveen. But my understanding is that coprocessors are for base only, not plain HDFS M/R

Comment: Chris - Do you mean HBase and not base? What's stopping coprocessors being used in an MR? I posted a query in the HBase groups for the difference between coprocessors and filters, but haven't got a response.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, meant HBase.  I meant that the OP was asking about M/R on native HDFS- I just mentioned HBase because he was asking about reading in only partial data.

Answer (score 1):

One answer is looking at the way that hive solves this problem. The data is in "tables" which are really just meta data about files on disk. Hive allows you to set columns on which a table is partitioned. This creates a separate folder for each partition so if you were partitioning a file by date you would have:

```
/mytable/2011-12-01
/mytable/2011-12-02
```

Inside of the date directory would be you actual files. So if you then ran a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE dt ='2011-12-01'
```

Only files in /mytable/2011-12-01 would be fed into the job.

Tho bottom line is that if you want functionality like this you either want to move to a higher level language (hive/pig) or you need to roll your own solutions.

Comment: Just FYI, this technique is called "partitioning". It was used in the relational databases for quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

Big part of the processing cost - is data parsing to produce Key-Values to the Mapper. We create there (usually) one java object per value + some container. It is costly both in terms of CPU and garbage collector pressure 
I would suggest the solution "in the middle". You can write input format which will read the input stream and skip non-relevant data in the early stage (for example by looking into few first bytes of the string). 
 As a result you will read all data, but actually parse and pass to the Mapper - only portion of it.
Another approach I would consider - is to use RCFile format (or other columnar format), and take care that relevant and non relevant data will sit in the different columns.

Answer (score 0):

If the files that you want to process have some unique attribute about their filename (like extension or partial filename match), you can also use the setInputPathFilter method of FileInputFormat to ignore all but the ones you want for your MR job. Hadoop by default ignores all ".xxx" and _xxx" files/dirs, but you can extend with setInputPathFilter.

As others have noted above, you will likely get sub-optimal performance out of your cluster doing something like this which breaks the "one block per mapper" paradigm, but sometimes this is acceptable. Can sometimes take more to "do it right", esp if you're dealing with a small amount of data & the time to re-architect and/or re-dump into HBase would eclipse the extra time required to run your job sub-optimally.